# How to fix VC2015 redistributables on Win10 install error "failed to install msi package"

Tags: windows, visual-studio, installation, redistributable

I am getting error 0x80070643 "failed to install msi package" on my Windows 10 Pro 64bit.

I need the redistributabels o e.g. run new builds of Apache and PHP. (And some other things I have pu off upgrading for a long time.)

It does not matter if I am trying to install vc_redist.x86.exe or vc_redist.x64.exe

I have tried to be logged in as administrator and right clicking "run as administrator"

It seems you can not extract the dlls manually using e.g. 7zip in new VC redistributables.

I have system restore disabled due lack of space on my system drive.

...

I am including the log:

> [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:09]i001: Burn v3.7.3813.0, Windows v10.0
>   (Build 10240: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\Thomas
>   Schulz\Downloads\vc_redist.x64.exe, cmdline: '-burn.unelevated
>   BurnPipe.{B9694083-EC81-464A-A1D2-5F81D5BDA77B}
>   {ED5B5629-12E8-4850-B580-C3C14DF149AC} 7252'
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:09]i000: Setting string variable
>   'WixBundleLog' to value
>   'X:\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170201033709.log'
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:09]i000: Setting string variable
>   'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\Thomas
>   Schulz\Downloads\vc_redist.x64.exe'
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:09]i000: Setting string variable
>   'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\Thomas
>   Schulz\Downloads\' [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:09]i000: Setting
>   string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015
>   Redistributable (x64) - 14.0.23026'
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:09]i100: Detect begin, 10 packages
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:09]i000: File search:
>   windows_uCRT_DetectKey, did not find path:
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:09]i000: File search:
>   windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists, did not find path:
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:09]i000: Setting numeric variable
>   'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 0
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i052: Condition
>   '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >=
>   v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i052: Condition
>   '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >=
>   v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i052: Condition
>   '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >=
>   v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i052: Condition
>   '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >=
>   v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i052: Condition
>   '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >=
>   v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i052: Condition
>   '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >=
>   v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i052: Condition
>   '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >=
>   v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i052: Condition
>   '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >=
>   v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i101: Detected package:
>   vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, cached: Complete
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i101: Detected package:
>   vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, cached: Complete
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86,
>   state: Absent, cached: None [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i101:
>   Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86,
>   state: Absent, cached: None [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i101:
>   Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i101: Detected package:
>   Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i101: Detected package:
>   Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i101: Detected package:
>   WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i101: Detected package:
>   WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64 >= v6.0
>   OR (VersionNT64 = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true.
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:10]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i200: Plan begin, 10 packages, action:
>   Install [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i052: Condition
>   '(VersionNT64)' evaluates to true.
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i000: Setting string variable
>   'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value
>   'X:\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170201033709_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64_rollback.log'
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i000: Setting string variable
>   'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value
>   'X:\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170201033709_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.log'
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64)'
>   evaluates to true. [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i000: Setting
>   string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to
>   value
>   'X:\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170201033709_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64_rollback.log'
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i000: Setting string variable
>   'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value
>   'X:\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170201033709_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.log'
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND
>   NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]w321: Skipping dependency registration
>   on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND
>   VersionNT64' evaluates to false. [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]w321:
>   Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency
>   providers: Windows81_x64 [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i052:
>   Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]w321: Skipping dependency registration
>   on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND
>   VersionNT64' evaluates to false. [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]w321:
>   Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency
>   providers: Windows8_x64 [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i052:
>   Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]w321: Skipping dependency registration
>   on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND
>   VersionNT64' evaluates to false. [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]w321:
>   Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency
>   providers: Windows7_MSU_x64 [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i052:
>   Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]w321: Skipping dependency registration
>   on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x86
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND
>   VersionNT64' evaluates to false. [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]w321:
>   Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency
>   providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x64 [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i201:
>   Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, default
>   requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback:
>   Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i201: Planned package:
>   vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba
>   requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No,
>   uncache: No, dependency: Register
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86,
>   state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent,
>   execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency:
>   None [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i201: Planned package:
>   Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested:
>   Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No,
>   dependency: None [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i201: Planned
>   package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba
>   requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache:
>   No, dependency: None [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i201: Planned
>   package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba
>   requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache:
>   No, dependency: None [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i201: Planned
>   package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent,
>   ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No,
>   uncache: No, dependency: None [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i201:
>   Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested:
>   Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache:
>   No, uncache: No, dependency: None
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i201: Planned package:
>   WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba
>   requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache:
>   No, dependency: None [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i201: Planned
>   package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested:
>   Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache:
>   No, uncache: No, dependency: None
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i300: Apply begin
>   [1C54:2628][2017-02-01T03:37:12]i360: Creating a system restore point.
>   [1C54:2628][2017-02-01T03:40:16]i361: Created a system restore point.
>   [1C54:2628][2017-02-01T03:40:16]i370: Session begin, registration key:
>   SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83},
>   options: 0x7, disable resume: No [1C54:2628][2017-02-01T03:40:16]i000:
>   Caching bundle from:
>   'X:\AppData\Local\Temp{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}.be\VC_redist.x64.exe'
>   to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}\VC_redist.x64.exe'
>   [1C54:2628][2017-02-01T03:40:16]i320: Registering bundle dependency
>   provider: {e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, version:
>   14.0.23026.0 [1C54:2628][2017-02-01T03:40:16]i371: Updating session, registration key:
>   SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83},
>   resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
>   [1C54:29DC][2017-02-01T03:40:16]i304: Verified existing payload:
>   vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{0D3E9E15-DE7A-300B-96F1-B4AF12B96488}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi.
>   [1C54:29DC][2017-02-01T03:40:17]i304: Verified existing payload:
>   cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{0D3E9E15-DE7A-300B-96F1-B4AF12B96488}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\cab1.cab.
>   [1C54:29DC][2017-02-01T03:40:17]i304: Verified existing payload:
>   vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{BC958BD2-5DAC-3862-BB1A-C1BE0790438D}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi.
>   [1C54:29DC][2017-02-01T03:40:18]i304: Verified existing payload:
>   cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{BC958BD2-5DAC-3862-BB1A-C1BE0790438D}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\cab1.cab. [1C54:2628][2017-02-01T03:40:18]i301: Applying execute package:
>   vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{0D3E9E15-DE7A-300B-96F1-B4AF12B96488}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi,
>   arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
>   [1C54:2628][2017-02-01T03:40:18]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to
>   install MSI package. [1C54:2628][2017-02-01T03:40:18]e000: Error
>   0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:40:18]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to
>   configure per-machine MSI package.
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:40:18]i319: Applied execute package:
>   vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:40:18]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to
>   execute MSI package. [1C54:2628][2017-02-01T03:40:18]i372: Session
>   end, registration key:
>   SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83},
>   resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
>   [1C54:2628][2017-02-01T03:40:18]i330: Removed bundle dependency
>   provider: {e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}
>   [1C54:2628][2017-02-01T03:40:18]i352: Removing cached bundle:
>   {e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, from path:
>   C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}\
>   [1C54:2628][2017-02-01T03:40:18]i371: Updating session, registration
>   key:
>   SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83},
>   resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
>   [1710:2944][2017-02-01T03:40:18]i399: Apply complete, result:
>   0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No

Comment: Start by making sure Windows is up to date.  (Some of those log entries suggest that the CRT, which is a Windows component, may be missing or out of date.)

Comment: BTW, does you install VS 2015 on your computer? There have the default Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64)/(x86) versions shipped with VS 2015, go to Control Panel—programs and Feature to check if there have any Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64)/(x86) versions or not.

Comment: You can have a try with 1. Check installed windows updates and if the update ‘KB2918614’ is existing, uninstall it and reinstall VC 2015 redistributable 2.  Run the command: sfc /scannow to verify the integrity of the required system files 3. Repair or uninstall any Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64)/(x86), redownload it https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=48145 and install. If this issue persists, use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the logs. You will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder, upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.

Comment: @MSFT I do not have VS 2015 - but I need the redistributable to run e.g. new Apache and PHP builds (and some other things as well which I have ignored sofar) --- I do not have have the KB2918614 in "View installed updates". I have many old redistributables 2005-2013 installed, but not any newer than that. I will try the other things you suggest as well

Comment: @MSFT Well, I am getting ""windows resource protection could not run the requested operation" when using scannow /sfc - I have created this: http://superuser.com/questions/1173900/how-to-solve-windows-resource-protection-could-not-run-when-using-sfc-scannow and will try work on solving it

Comment: Build 10240 is the original windows 10 from july 2015. update to version 1607 Build 14393

Comment: Okay - after a lot of sfc, dsim, failed chkdsk, blue screens with ntfs errors, removing los of anivurs and other files I finally got a stable system where I could aslo upgrade to latest Windows 10 without error + VS redistribuables

Comment: @Tom, so glad to hear that your issue is solved and you can share your workaround when you have free time, that will help other community members who meet the same or similar issue to search this useful information.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT I really spent two days running sfc, dsim, chkdsk + remove e.g. Avira (it had made a 20+ GB directory on my system disk... I think hat acually helped on chkdsk, but I am not sure)  --- should I put my finger on a single thing i would be "sfc /scannow" that helped quite a bit

Comment: @Tom, you can add the command: sfc /scannow as a reply and mark as answer after 24 hours, it seems there have some issues or broken of your OS and this command help you to fix it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution was a combination of the following with most important first and all run multiple times:

- sfc /scannow
- removing a 20gb direcory generated by anti virus on my system disk
- chkdsk with /r repair command
- waiting a lot (entire process lasted 48 hours)
- removing everything else unnecessary on system drive
- uninstalling anti virus
- dsim commands
- reboots where windows went into recovery mode

Comment: Hi Tom, sorry to trouble you and thank you for your sharing, could you please mark your reply as answer when you have free time, and it will help other community members to easier search this useful information :)